# searching database using php sessions doesn't return any results or errors

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to search my database using PHP sessions from a posted form in a previous page but the search does't return any syntax errors non results.

Comment: You may want to read about [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) as the code you wrote is vulnerable.

Comment: hey Dan, thank you so much .. i read about it but i'm trying to teach myself how to appropriately use PHP with MYSQL since It is my very first attempt at this :)

Comment: Looks like the problem is with your fetch_array statement: it should be `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`.  Or, you might prefer to use `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`.  If you're just learning, I would suggest using PDO instead.

Comment: ...and, after looking closer at your query and the output, I doubt that the query is correct.  If you'd like more help, please edit your question and add the schema of your `students` table, along with a *small* subset of data and expected results.

Comment: @TimMorton thank you tim .. here i updated the question to include all the information required.

Comment: So the thing that you're getting from the db is a list of student names and their attendance, having the named faculty/degree/course?  I'll take a look at it again after work.

Comment: BTW, do you get anything back, or just a white screen?

Comment: thank you @TimMorton .. i get no data at all

Comment: My point being, do you have an error that isn't showing?  If you get html output, you at least know that there isn't an error.  But if you get nothing, then you need to turn error reporting on or check the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a disclaimer:  I don't work with mysqli nor PDO; I use my own database abstraction.  So you will need to verify my example with the documentation.

I first tried to write an answer demonstrating the use of parameters in mysqli, but quite frankly mysqli is... *ugly*.  Extremely ugly and rather unwieldy.

If you need to add sessions in, you can do so once you get a basic prototype working. Instead of dealing with sessions, I'm addressing the basics of database access.  Please don't consider this to be cut and paste code: it may or may not work, because I am not able to test it.  It is intended to be a suggestion and starting point for you to build on.

```
<?php

//session_start(); // not needed for this example

function get_post($var_name) {
  $out = '';
  if(array_key_exists($var_name,$_POST)) {
    $out = $_POST[$var_name];
  }
  return $out;
}

// whenever you have to do something over, break it out into a function
$faculty = get_post('fac');
$degree  = get_post('degree');
$course  = get_post('course');


// set up PDO connection
// this section credit to https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'students';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

// helpful initializations, such as default fetch is associative array
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);


// note that the first time the page is accessed, 
// the POST variables will be saved as empty strings, 
// so the query will execute fine, but won't find any results.

$query= 'SELECT name,faculty,degree,course,attend ' . 
        'FROM students ' . 
        'WHERE faculty=? AND degree=? AND course=? ' . 
        'ORDER BY name';

$pdo->prepare($query);
$result = $pdo->execute([$faculty, $degree, $course]); // don't miss the [] which is a shortcut for array()

// notice, try to keep PHP and HTML presentation separate,
// with PHP on top. (advanced: learn MVC)
// now that we have access to our data, present the html
// The HTML could be in another file and simply required() here. 

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Staff List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <img src="login10.png" id="logos"/>
    <h2 id="inf">Staff List </h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="fac">Faculty :</label>
        <select id="fac" name="fac" required>
          <option value="">Select course Faculty ..</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
          <option value="pharmaceutical">pharmaceutical</option>
          <option value="Sport">Sport </option>
          <option value="Science">Science </option>
        </select> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <label for="degree">Degree :</label>
        <select id="degree" name="degree" required>
          <option value="">Select Course Degree..</option>
          <option value="Associate degree">Associate degree</option>
          <option value="Bachelor degree">Bachelor degree</option>
          <option value="Master degree">Master degree </option>
          <option value="Doctoral degree">Doctoral degree </option>
        </select> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <label for="course">Required Course :</label>
          <input type="text" name="course" id="course" class="text" placeholder="Enter Course Name" required>

      </li>
      <li>
          <label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
              <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Student List">
          </li>
      </ul>
    </form> 

    <?php if($faculty && $degree && $course): ?>
      <hr>

      <h2>Results</h2>
      <table>
      <?php while ($row = $result->fetch()): ?>
        <tr class="data"> <!-- can't use id="data" because id has to be unique -->
          <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $row['faculty'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $row['degree'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $row['course'] ?></td>
          <td class="colors"><?= $row['attend'] ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much @Tim i used your solution as a demonstration and i got the results back to my table. man i can't thank you hard enough for this.  and as part of your answer you mentioned mysqli - the reason i chose it is because i'm good at mysql itself but i have never used it with anything else apart from java. anyway thank you so much again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM students WHERE faculty ='" . $fa. "' AND 
         degree ='" . $de . "' AND course ='" . $co . "' ORDER BY name";
```

Oh, and please use prepared statement. This solution is very insecure!!

You can read more about prepared statement below:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Good job noting prepared statements. You could make the answer better by showing it as a prepared statement, since she's just learning; might as well learn the right way.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you so much..i tried your solution but i didn't get any data back. can my syntax be incorrect (the variables aren't saving in the sessions to begin with) and thank you for the link i'm implementing the changes once i get the hang of it